# error when trying to link with static c standard library

Tags: c, assembly, linker, static-libraries

My OS is ubuntu 14.04 32bit and my source program test.c is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("test.");
        return;
}
```

I compile it with command :

```
gcc -S test.c
```

which output as a test.s file. I assemble it with command :

```
as -o test.o test.s
```

then I want to link it with c standard library statically. I searched for `libc.a` file , located it at `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a`. so I tried to link it with command:

```
ld test.o /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

but comes out with a lot of error message:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048210
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(backtrace.o): In function `backtrace_helper':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetIP'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(backtrace.o): In function `backtrace_helper':
(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetGR'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(backtrace.o): In function `backtrace_helper':
(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `_Unwind_GetCFA'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(backtrace.o): In function `__backtrace':
(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Backtrace'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofclose.o): In function `_IO_new_fclose':
(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofclose.o):(.eh_frame+0x167): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofflush.o): In function `_IO_fflush':
(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofflush.o):(.eh_frame+0xdf): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofputs.o): In function `_IO_fputs':
(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofputs.o):(.eh_frame+0xdf): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofwrite.o): In function `_IO_fwrite':
(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iofwrite.o):(.eh_frame+0xdf): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iogetdelim.o): In function `_IO_getdelim':
(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(iogetdelim.o):(.eh_frame+0xdf): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(wfileops.o): In function `_IO_wfile_underflow':
(.text+0x5fc): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(wfileops.o):(.eh_frame+0x137): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(fileops.o): In function `_IO_new_file_underflow':
(.text+0x40b): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(fileops.o):(.eh_frame+0x1b3): undefined reference to `__gcc_personality_v0'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(strtof_l.o): In function `____strtof_l_internal':
(.text+0xbc6): undefined reference to `__divdi3'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(strtof_l.o): In function `____strtof_l_internal':
(.text+0xc08): undefined reference to `__moddi3'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(strtof_l.o): In function `____strtof_l_internal':
(.text+0x249d): undefined reference to `__divdi3'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(strtod_l.o): In function `____strtod_l_internal':
(.text+0xcc9): undefined reference to `__divdi3'
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.a(strtod_l.o): In function `____strtod_l_internal':
(.text+0xd0b): undefined reference to `__moddi3'
...
...
```

My question is, why these error messages ? I'm trying to learn how the compiling system works, so instead of knowing how to solve this problem I 'm more desiring to know how it comes this way. It seems that the static C library depends on other libraries, why and what are those libraries ?

EDIT:
I'm doing this because I want to know how things work so I'd rather avoid the `gcc` script.

Comment: Why do you do these steps separately instead of just using the GCC frontend program? I also suggest you use the GCC option `-v` to see what GCC add for internal libraries.

Comment: because I'm trying to learn the compiling system, so I'd rather to "handcraft" work to see how every step is done.

Comment: Then use the verbose option to see what GCC does.

Comment: BTW Ubuntu 14.04 is really old. You should upgrade it (then you'll get a more recent `gcc` ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) startup object files (in addition of static `libc.a`), which notably are defining the `_start` entry point (in your [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable) and contain [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific (prologue and epilog) code to call your `main` (and finally process [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) registered handlers and stdio flushing). The low-level [libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html) is also needed. Details are complex and implementation specific. To understand them, compile your test code as

```
gcc -v -static test.c -o mytest
```

<sup>(avoid calling an executable `test` because it would collide with `/usr/bin/test` or with the builtin of your shell)</sup>

In practice, better at least link with `gcc`

If you are curious, take advantage that Linux is mostly [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) and study the source code (e.g. of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), of [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), etc...). You might find [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) interesting.

> I'd rather avoid the `gcc` script

Technically, `gcc` is *not* a script but a driver program (see [gcc/gcc.c](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/gcc.c?view=markup) in the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). But it will run `ld` which indeed runs some [linker scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.27/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts). The actual compilation is done by [cc1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) which is started by the `gcc` program.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I saw quite a few French names in the README file but not yours, are you involved in this development?

Comment: I'm one of the [MAINTAINERS](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/MAINTAINERS?view=markup) of GCC. I'm French, but of Russian ascent. See also http://gcc-melt.org/

Comment: Normally people would say they're of Russian *descent*, meaning that they are descendants of Russian ancestors.  Does French or Russian terminology for family trees translate literally as "ascending" the tree or something?

Comment: Ok, I am not a native English speaker. But all my 4 grandparents were Russians.

Comment: thanks for the reply , the gcc verbose output is so comprehensive for me , I think I'm not ready for that yet, I'll try to learn something more.

Answer (score 3):

You must also link the `gcc` intrinsic library.  The easiest way to do this is to use the `gcc` front-end to compile and link with the `-static` option:

```
gcc -static -o test test.c
```

If you insist on compiling from assembly, you can do this:

```
gcc -static -o test test.s
```

Static linking may not be supported on your system.

EDIT: giving gcc the `-v` option will tell you what commands it executes.